# Show that if $f \in L^n(0,1), f \ge 0$, then $\int_{0}^{1} \ln(1+f(x))\,dx \leq \ln(1+\int_{0}^{1} f(x)\,dx).$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Show that if $f \in L^n(0,1), f \ge 0$, then $$\int_{0}^{1} \ln(1+f(x))\,dx \leq \ln(1+\int_{0}^{1} f(x)\,dx).$$

I tried to expand the logarithmic on the left side of the integral and got $$\int_{0}^{1} f(x)-\frac{f(x)^2}{2}+\frac{f(x)^3}{3}+\cdots,$$
but I am not able to take it forward to reach the desired result.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Do you know Jensen's inequality?

Comment: No, I do not know that Inequality.

Comment: Can you give me a hint? @PhoemueX